# Не устанавливается модуль vk_api.bot_longpoll

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот

Делаю бота для вк через vk_api. Нашла код где прописан import

```
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import vk_api
```

Но у меня нет этого модуля, pycharm показывает что их нет, хотя vk_api имеется. На ютубе смотрела, у людей работает. Как решить эту проблему. Обязательно нужен LongPoll. Прописывала pip install vk_api.bot_longpoll
ничего не находит.
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Внимательней нужно быть. `pip install vk_api`

Comment: Тк этот модуль есть у меня, он работает и даже установлен. Но для работы с longpoll нужно импортировать модуль с longpoll ом

Comment: Вот ссылка на пример кода: https://pastebin.com/dVKMrV1q

Comment: В модуле `vk_api` всё уже есть, ничего не нужно устанавливать. Все нужные библиотеки там:

VkApi (основной класс),
VkUpload,
VkTools,
Модуль longpoll (VkLongPoll),
Модуль bot_longpoll (VkBotLongPoll),
VkKeyboard,
VkAudio,
VkStreaming,
VkRequestsPool,
VkFunction,

Comment: Вот даже в самом примере на github от разработчиков есть пример с longpoll: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/bot_longpoll.py     Я ее вставляю и pycharm ее не видит, подсвечивает красным, как будто этой библиотеки там нет

Comment: Попробуйте написать код, дальше посмотрим, что будем.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Вы установили `vk_api` в одну версию Python с помощью его `pip install`, а интерпретатор Вашего проекта использует другую версию (или виртуальное окружение), где эта библиотека не устанавливалась.

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой. Решил так: "pip install vk-api"
Вместо "_" пишите "-" и все заработает